# URL is changing in magento

Tags: php, magento, http, redirect

Here I want to ask two question.
I upload my magento website from localhost to main server. My website link is this

http://bigtechideas.com/dope

Problem:1 - When I open url http://bigtechideas.com/dope/admin it returns this http://bigtechideas.com/dopeindex.php/admin
Why it add index.php in url ?

Problem:2 - When I open **http**://bigtechideas.com/dope it returns me **https**://bigtechideas.com/dope

Why it add **HTTPS** in url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all configured through the Magento backend. You have to set an URL for unecrypted and encrypted pages (http & https) in the settings. If you move a Magento installation from one server to anther you have to edit those URLs.

You could also use the following SQL snippets to directly **modify the settings in the database**. (I can't guarantee that it is complete, but it should)

```
-- move Magento to another server
SET @shop_domain = 'YOUR_NEW_DOMAIN_WITHOUT_HTTP_HERE',
  @secure_protocol = 'https://'; -- set to http:// if no certificate is available

UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = CONCAT('http://', @shop_domain, '/') WHERE `path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = CONCAT(@secure_protocol, @shop_domain, '/') WHERE `path` = 'web/secure/base_url';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = CONCAT('http://', @shop_domain, '/media/') WHERE `path` = 'web/unsecure/base_media_url';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = CONCAT(@secure_protocol, @shop_domain, '/media/') WHERE `path` = 'web/secure/base_media_url';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = @shop_domain WHERE `path` = 'web/cookie/cookie_domain';
```

You also have to **clear the cache** after those changes.

Answer (score 0):

Do The Following

in production db,in its core_config_data table, you should find every records containing the url of your local installation, then you need to update those values

this query may help you

```
SELECT *
     FROM `core_config_data`
     WHERE `value` LIKE 'http://%';
```

Do not forget to delete  var folder contents